# Ubuntu LDAP Client: Caching not working

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-16.04, credentials, pam-ldap

I have an LDAP server, and I want to be able to login on my machines using that LDAP server. This works basically, but when the LDAP server is out of reach (e.g. a laptop is used outside the office) then authentication fails.

I tried several approaches to address this issue.

(1) pam_ccreds.so: I followed this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PamCcredsHowto document but ended up with login failing:

```
> su testuser
Password: <pwd entered>
You have been logged on using cached credentials.
su: Authentication failure
```

That is, apparently *something* worked but *some other thing* later did not. This had happened to [someone else](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZqb3oi63WAhUFNxQKHYMtB1wQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fubuntuforums.org%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D1585654&usg=AFQjCNHBQjNuF8VdWwLuYB_KJSowVc-Q8A) but the alleged solution (allow if LDAP server not reachable) does not seem to be a solution at all.

(2) I fiddled around with nslcd. I added some debug outputs and found this:

```
<passwd=4294967295> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=mytld", filter="(&(uid=*)(uidNumber=4294967295))")
```

The UID 4294967295 was suspicious to me (it actually should be 1000002), and yes, there are other reports of that UID (which is -1 in signed representation of the int), but all these reports and solutions appeared to be connected with samba and/or winbind -- this is not the case in my setup.

So I have already spent a great deal of time, I am merely trying because I actually do not understand how the credential caching with nlscd really works. I think I got the grasp of pam_ccred but from what I found in the net I got the impression that this thing never really worked with LDAP and/or is not really maintained.

My specific questions are:

1. On an Ubuntu (16.04) client system, is there a recommended way of how to be able to login with the LDAP user/password when the LDAP server is not reachable?
2. When things do not work as expected, which actions can I take to produce reasonable debug outputs (such as nslcd)?
3. Where can the strange UID come from?

Thanks very much for any effort, pointer or input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to build the kind of setup you want using pam-ldapd/pam-ccreds etc. it is much easier to get the same result using [sssd](https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd) (and pam-sssd, and nss-sssd). See e.g. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Enterprise/Authentication/sssd

Comment: Thank you, ptman, I followed your advice and chose sssd over ccreds. Problem solved.